# How to type cast dynamically the value of the field?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am working on an Lightning Web Component in which User can create record for any sobject. User first select the sobject, then its field and a custom form will appear through which user can enter the value for the selected field. On save an apex class is called with map having key as field_api_name and value as its value entered by user. All input tag in custom form is of text type. So when I try to put the value for some field which is of Double type then an error is shown `System.SObjectException: Illegal assignment from String to Decimal`. I need to type cast the value of field dynamically.

Consider the following code as an example:

```
        string val = '2000';
        string name = 'TypeCast';
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.put('Name',name);
        acc.put('Average_Product_Price__c', val);
        insert acc;
```

above code is giving same error : `System.SObjectException: Illegal assignment from String to Decimal`

PS : I can't use Lightning-record-form as it doesn't suit my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix to the lines of code you show would be:

```
decimal val = 2000;
```

But to write more dynamic code you will need to do type conversion of say strings that come from the client-side to various Apex types. That means using describe data such as [DescribeFieldResult.getType()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_getType) and then various parse methods such as `Decimal.valueOf` depending on the required field type.

Building that out is time consuming and error prone. I recommend you take another look at what Salesforce provides because they have already done all that work.